# Go Nil Dereference Error When Testing HTTP Request

Tags: go

I am trying to test a HTTP request in my Go library. Object which makes the call accepts a HTTP client object via dependency injection so in my test I am mocking the HTTP client like this:

```
func TestMyObject(t *testing.T) {
    server := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.WriteHeader(200)
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        fmt.Fprintln(w, mockJSONResponse)
    }))
    defer server.Close()

    // Make a transport that reroutes all traffic to the example server
    transport := &http.Transport{
        Proxy: func(req *http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
            return url.Parse(server.URL)
        },
    }

    // Make a http.Client with the transport
    httpClient := &http.Client{Transport: transport}

    // I am passing the httpClient to my object
}
```

Here is how the HTTP request is made within my object:

```
// Make - makes a prepared HTTP request
func (ir *MyObject) Make() *http.Response {
    if ir.Err != nil {
        return nil
    }

    ir.resp, ir.Err = ir.Client.Do(ir.req)

    runtime.SetFinalizer(ir, func(ir *MyObject) {
        ir.resp.Body.Close()
    })

    ir.logReqRes()
    ir.checkErrorResponse()

    return ir.resp
}
```

I am getting nil pointer dereference error though:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

In this function (I am trying to log the response):

```
// Logs request and response
func (ir *MyObject) logReqRes() {
    log.Print("AAAAAAA")
    log.Print(ir.resp)
    log.Print("AAAAAAA")
    if reqInfo, err := httputil.DumpRequest(ir.req, true); err == nil {
        log.Print("Logging request:")
        log.Print(string(reqInfo))
    }
    if respInfo, err := httputil.DumpResponse(ir.resp, true); err == nil {
        log.Print("Logging response:")
        log.Print(string(respInfo))
    }
}
```

As you can see, ir.resp is nil for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: shouldn't you be checking ir.Err _after_ you call ir.Client.Do in Make()? Additionally, before "return nil" you should call log.Print(ir.Err) to get the error message.

Comment: Thanks guys. I figured this out. Look at my answer. The check for ir.Err is correct there as I have other methods than Make on the struct (Prepare for example, which builds the HTTP request). And in my code I want to minimise repetitive error checks so all methods just skip their body if one of previous methods of the struct failed. I then handle the error at the end. All needed to figure this out was to add few log.Print(ir.Err) into my code and it became easy to see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found an issue. Better logging of errors actually showed that my mistake was very simple.

I was passing this as a URL to mocked HTTP client:

```
host/api/v1/tokens/
```

Which was resulting in this error:

```
Post host/api/v1/tokens/: unsupported protocol scheme
```

Apparently the URL must include a proper HTTP scheme (http://) even when you are using a test server.